# jQuery UI Slider Incorrect Value

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm creating a web page that allows users to select a value using the jQuery UI Slider. However, I would like to update the values as the user is scrolling, so I attached a **update_value** function to the sliders **slide** event.

The issue is that when the slider handle gets to the edges, the value I get is incorrect. For example, I get a value of 500 when it should be 0, and 99000 when it should be max. (100000).

I tried testing with the **change** event, and it gives me the exact value required. However, the problem is still there when I try using the **slide** event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it! The problem is that using:

`$('slider').value()`

Doesn't give the exact value for some reason. However, by modifying the update_value function to:

`function update_value(event, ui)`

and using ui.value solved the problem.

Comment: I love it when I google for something and it finds a Stack Overflow page.  You know you're probably gonna resolve your issue :D